# How to do decimal filtering using @inovua/reactdatagrid-community react?

Tags: reactjs, filter, datagrid

I'm trying to do is decimal filtering using this package:

Incoming data in its simplest form is like this:

```
"Odds":[
{
"HomeOdd": 2.39,
"DrawOdd": 4.26,
"AwayOdd": 2.61,
"HomeOpenOdd": 2.45,
"DrawOpenOdd": 3.84,
"AwayOpenOdd": 2.8
}
]
```

I classify the data again like this

```
match.Match1x2Data.forEach(matchData => {
                 matchData.Odds.forEach(data => {
                     fullData.HT1_Opening.push(data.HomeOpenOdd);
                     fullData.HT1_Closing.push(data.HomeOdd);
                 });
         });
```

```
const filterValue = [
{ name: 'HT1_Opening', operator: 'gte', type: 'number' },
{ name: 'HT1_Closing', operator: 'gte', type: 'number' },
];
const columns = [
{
name: 'HT1_Opening',
header: 'HT1/O',
group: 'HT1',
filterEditor: NumberFilter
},
];

return (
<div>
<ReactDataGrid
i18n={customI18n}
idProperty="id"
columns={columns}
dataSource={dataSource}
style={gridStyle}
defaultFilterValue={filterValue}
scrollProps={scrollProps}
groups={groups}
pagination
/>
</div>
);
```

[https://reactdatagri](https://stackoverflow.com)[d](https://reactdatagrid.io/docs/)[.io/docs/](https://stackoverflow.com)

I looked at the documentation, unfortunately I couldn't find anything.

What I want to do is just decimal filtering by using this package or manipulating it. What do you think I should do?

This package only has NumberFilter for numbers. I tried using NumberFilter and StringFilter for decimal filtering but failed.